# Call to a member function publish()

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, joomla-component

i have created a joomla component and when i click on publish and unpublish button in admin then i am getting such error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function publish() on boolean in ...\libraries\legacy\controller\admin.php on line 209

Please help

**UPDATE**

my View.html.php

```
    require_once JPATH_COMPONENT . '/helpers/lab.php';

    class labViewStructurelist extends JViewLegacy
    {
        protected $structurelist;
        protected $pagination;
        public $filterForm;
        public $activeFilters;public $state;
        public function display($tpl = null)
        {


            $this->structurelist = $this->get('Items');
            $this->pagination   = $this->get('Pagination');
            $this->state = $this->get('State');
            //print_r($this->pagination->pagesTotal);die();
            $this->filterForm    = $this->get('FilterForm');
            $this->activeFilters = $this->get('ActiveFilters');

            $this->addToolBar();
            $this->sidebar = JHtmlSidebar::render();
            if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors')))
            {
                JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));

                return false;
            }

            return parent::display($tpl);
        }

        protected function addToolBar() {
            JToolBarHelper::title( JText::_('COM_LAB_LAB_DDDD'), 'generic.png' );

            JToolBarHelper::publish('Structurelist.publish');
            JToolBarHelper::unpublish('Structurelist.unpublish');
            JToolBarHelper::deleteList('', 'patients.delete', 'JTOOLBAR_DELETE');
            JToolBarHelper::preferences('com_lab');
        }

}
```

**Controller/stricturelist.php**

```
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import Joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controlleradmin');


class LabControllerStructurelist extends  JControllerAdmin
{


         public function getModel($name='Structurelist',$prefix='ssModel',$config=array('ignore_request'=>true))
         {
             $model=parent::getModel($name,$prefix,$config);

             return $model;
         }

}
```

**models\structurelist.php**

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport('joomla.application.component.modellist');
JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');
class LabModelStructurelist extends JModelList{

    public function __construct($config = array())
    {
        if (empty($config['filter_fields']))
        {
            $config['filter_fields'] = array(
                'id', 'a.id',
                'fullname', 'a.fullname',
            );

            $assoc = JLanguageAssociations::isEnabled();

            if ($assoc)
            {
                $config['filter_fields'][] = 'association';
            }
        }

        parent::__construct($config);
    }



    public function getListQuery()
    {

        $db    = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);


        $query->select('*');
        $query->from('#__ss_structure_tmp');
        $search = $this->getState('filter.search');
        $limit = $this->getState('filter.limit');
        if (!empty($search)) {

            $query->where('fullname LIKE "%' . $search .'%" ' );
        }
        if (!empty($limit)) {

            $query->setLimit($limit);
        }

        return $query;
    }

    protected function populateState($ordering = 'a.fullname', $direction = 'asc')
    {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        if ($layout = $app->input->get('layout'))
        {
            $this->context .= '.' . $layout;
        }

        $search = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.filter.search', 'filter_search');
        $this->setState('filter.search', $search);


        parent::populateState();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the model to your controller using the `getModel()` method. Look in the `articles controller` of the `com_content` for example.

Comment: thank you,but i have a model , let me update my post

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a table file with the publish function within:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\Utilities\ArrayHelper;

class labTableStructurelist extends JTable
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param   JDatabase  &$db  A database connector object
     */
    public function __construct(&$db)
    {
        parent::__construct('#__ss_structure_tmp', 'id', $db);
    }

/**
 * Overloaded bind function to pre-process the params.
 *
 * @param   array  $array   Named array
 * @param   mixed  $ignore  Optional array or list of parameters to ignore
 *
 * @return  null|string  null is operation was satisfactory, otherwise returns an error
 *
 * @see     JTable:bind
 * @since   1.5
 */
public function bind($array, $ignore = '')
{
    $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $task = $input->getString('task', '');

    if (($task == 'save' || $task == 'apply') && (!JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.edit.state', 'com_lab.structurelist.'.$array['id']) && $array['state'] == 1))
    {
        $array['state'] = 0;
    }

    if ($array['id'] == 0)
    {
        $array['created_by'] = JFactory::getUser()->id;
    }

    if (isset($array['params']) && is_array($array['params']))
    {
        $registry = new JRegistry;
        $registry->loadArray($array['params']);
        $array['params'] = (string) $registry;
    }

    if (isset($array['metadata']) && is_array($array['metadata']))
    {
        $registry = new JRegistry;
        $registry->loadArray($array['metadata']);
        $array['metadata'] = (string) $registry;
    }

    if (!JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.admin', 'com_lab.structurelist.' . $array['id']))
    {
        $actions         = JAccess::getActionsFromFile(
            JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_lab/access.xml',
            "/access/section[@name='user']/"
        );
        $default_actions = JAccess::getAssetRules('com_lab.structurelist.' . $array['id'])->getData();
        $array_jaccess   = array();

        foreach ($actions as $action)
        {
            $array_jaccess[$action->name] = $default_actions[$action->name];
        }

        $array['rules'] = $this->JAccessRulestoArray($array_jaccess);
    }

    // Bind the rules for ACL where supported.
    if (isset($array['rules']) && is_array($array['rules']))
    {
        $this->setRules($array['rules']);
    }

    return parent::bind($array, $ignore);
}

/**
 * This function convert an array of JAccessRule objects into an rules array.
 *
 * @param   array  $jaccessrules  An array of JAccessRule objects.
 *
 * @return  array
 */
private function JAccessRulestoArray($jaccessrules)
{
    $rules = array();

    foreach ($jaccessrules as $action => $jaccess)
    {
        $actions = array();

        foreach ($jaccess->getData() as $group => $allow)
        {
            $actions[$group] = ((bool) $allow);
        }

        $rules[$action] = $actions;
    }

    return $rules;
}

/**
 * Overloaded check function
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function check()
{
    // If there is an ordering column and this is a new row then get the next ordering value
    if (property_exists($this, 'ordering') && $this->id == 0)
    {
        $this->ordering = self::getNextOrder();
    }


    return parent::check();
}

/**
 * Method to set the publishing state for a row or list of rows in the database
 * table.  The method respects checked out rows by other users and will attempt
 * to checkin rows that it can after adjustments are made.
 *
 * @param   mixed    $pks     An optional array of primary key values to update.  If not
 *                            set the instance property value is used.
 * @param   integer  $state   The publishing state. eg. [0 = unpublished, 1 = published]
 * @param   integer  $userId  The user id of the user performing the operation.
 *
 * @return   boolean  True on success.
 *
 * @since    1.0.4
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function publish($pks = null, $state = 1, $userId = 0)
{
    // Initialise variables.
    $k = $this->_tbl_key;
    // Sanitize input.
    ArrayHelper::toInteger($pks);
    $userId = (int) $userId;
    $state  = (int) $state;
    // If there are no primary keys set check to see if the instance key is set.
    if (empty($pks))
    {
        if ($this->$k)
        {
            $pks = array($this->$k);
        }
        // Nothing to set publishing state on, return false.
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(500, JText::_('JLIB_DATABASE_ERROR_NO_ROWS_SELECTED'));
        }
    }
    // Build the WHERE clause for the primary keys.
    $where = $k . '=' . implode(' OR ' . $k . '=', $pks);
    // Determine if there is checkin support for the table.
    if (!property_exists($this, 'checked_out') || !property_exists($this, 'checked_out_time'))
    {
        $checkin = '';
    }
    else
    {
        $checkin = ' AND (checked_out = 0 OR checked_out = ' . (int) $userId . ')';
    }
    // Update the publishing state for rows with the given primary keys.
    $this->_db->setQuery(
        'UPDATE `' . $this->_tbl . '`' .
        ' SET `state` = ' . (int) $state .
        ' WHERE (' . $where . ')' .
        $checkin
    );
    $this->_db->execute();
    // If checkin is supported and all rows were adjusted, check them in.
    if ($checkin && (count($pks) == $this->_db->getAffectedRows()))
    {
        // Checkin each row.
        foreach ($pks as $pk)
        {
            $this->checkin($pk);
        }
    }
    // If the JTable instance value is in the list of primary keys that were set, set the instance.
    if (in_array($this->$k, $pks))
    {
        $this->state = $state;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Define a namespaced asset name for inclusion in the #__assets table
 *
 * @return string The asset name
 *
 * @see JTable::_getAssetName
 */
protected function _getAssetName()
{
    $k = $this->_tbl_key;

    return 'com_lab.structurelist.' . (int) $this->$k;
}

/**
 * Returns the parent asset's id. If you have a tree structure, retrieve the parent's id using the external key field
 *
 * @param   JTable   $table  Table name
 * @param   integer  $id     Id
 *
 * @see JTable::_getAssetParentId
 *
 * @return mixed The id on success, false on failure.
 */
protected function _getAssetParentId(JTable $table = null, $id = null)
{
    // We will retrieve the parent-asset from the Asset-table
    $assetParent = JTable::getInstance('Asset');

    // Default: if no asset-parent can be found we take the global asset
    $assetParentId = $assetParent->getRootId();

    // The item has the component as asset-parent
    $assetParent->loadByName('com_lab');

    // Return the found asset-parent-id
    if ($assetParent->id)
    {
        $assetParentId = $assetParent->id;
    }

    return $assetParentId;
}

/**
 * Delete a record by id
 *
 * @param   mixed  $pk  Primary key value to delete. Optional
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function delete($pk = null)
{
    $this->load($pk);
    $result = parent::delete($pk);

    return $result;
}
}
```

**Please note, that this is just an example of a table file, I can't guarantee that this would work just by copy&paste. Please check com_content/table for another example.**

Also add a getTable() to your List single item model:

```
public function getTable($type = 'view_name', $prefix = 'labTable', $config = array())
{
    return JTable::getInstance($type, $prefix, $config);
}
```

Please check if file structure is correct:

**List View**

```
structurelist**s** -> list view with multiple items
|-> controller/structurelists.php
|-> models/structurelists.php
|-> view/structurelists/
```

**Single View / List View (publish() for example)**

```
structurelist -> single item view (edit view)
|-> models/structurelist.php (this is important for the publish() in the list view)
|-> models/forms/structurelist.xml
|-> tables/structurelist.php (this is important for the publish() in the list view)
|-> view/structurelist/
```

Feel free to comment if you need more help.